# Selenium error when loading specific page “selenium Failed to resolve address”

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am creating a bot in python and when loading a page it shows the following errors on the console but it still runs but when I try to run anything that involves the page it crashes giving the information that the element was not found as if it had not loaded the page

```
[19268:23244:0220/122212.124:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(128)] Failed to resolve address for b61e8cb6-1616-485e-8ff4-278ce4d32d1e.local., errorcode: -105
[19268:23244:0220/122212.138:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(128)] Failed to resolve address for b61e8cb6-1616-485e-8ff4-278ce4d32d1e.local., errorcode: -105
```

already tried to reload the page but the same error.

part of the code that is giving error:

```
logar = driver.find_element_by_id("joinBtn")
        logar.click()
        sleep(10)

        driver.get(driver.current_url)
        sleep(10)
        microfone = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Entrar áudio por computador")
        microfone.click()
```

**is crashing when it reaches the line:**

```
microfone = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Entrar áudio por computador")
```

**error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/olope/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/botZoom/Zoom.py", line 142, in <module>
    schedule.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\olope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 563, in run_pending
    default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\olope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 94, in run_pending
    self._run_job(job)
  File "C:\Users\olope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 147, in _run_job
    ret = job.run()
  File "C:\Users\olope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 466, in run
    ret = self.job_func()
  File "c:/Users/olope/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/botZoom/Zoom.py", line 106, in entrar_reuniao
    microfone = driver.find_element_by_id("zm-btn join-audio-by-voip__join-btn zm-btn--primary zm-btn__outline--white zm-btn--lg")
  File "C:\Users\olope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\olope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
```

Comment: Those errors look like something that outputs when using the Chrome WebDriver. Are you using Chrome or Firefox? Also, you could try doing `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text()` -- what error are you getting when it crashes?

Comment: I'm using chrome, already tried the error in reality when you click on the login button and it loads a new page

Comment: I will try to use FireFox if I finish the question